# Is this the right way to test my ruby class?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, tdd

I am building an investment tool and want to **make sure that it calculates the right maturity amount**.

Here is some of the source code:

```
  def maturity_amount
    if cumulative
      amount = initial_deposit * (1 + (rate_of_interest)/4 ) ** (term * 4)
      amount.round
    else
      initial_deposit
    end
  end
```

So I write a test like this:

```
it "can calculate interest earned" do
   investment = FactoryGirl.build(:investment, initial_deposit: 250000, rate_of_interest: 9.5, cumulative: true)
   expect(investment.maturity_amount).to eq(331335)
end
```

You see here I hardcode the results into the test. Does this make the test fragile? Also I can't seem to vary the inputs I give to the test easily without updating the end result every time.

So is there a better way to write a test and still be confident about making the correct calculation? Should I be mocking? Or should I not be writing tests like these in the first place? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks ok! The test is far from fragile. The test will only fail if you change the inputs or the algorithm, which are precisely the conditions under which it should fail. Test's should not have any logic or metaprogramming in them.

If you're not doing things differently based on inputs, there is no need to write many tests with varying inputs. This will increase the maintainence burden of your test suite without adding any value.

Simple is better.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of your maturity amount is dependent on certain conditions, I think it needs more testing.  Here's how I would probably spec the behaviour of your method (and slightly refactor your class).
I'm going to assume your class is named `Investment`:

```
class Investment
  def maturity_amount
    if cumulative
      # kept the `.round` out here in case you had other functions
      # that may take the `ceil` or `floor` etc of `interest_earned`
      interest_earned.round
    else
      initial_deposit
    end
  end

  # Refactor out the formula into its own method so it can
  # be tested in isolation
  def interest_earned
    initial_deposit * (1 + (rate_of_interest)/4 ) ** (term * 4)
  end
end

describe Investment do
  let(:investment) { described_class.new }

  describe '#maturity_amount' do
    let(:maturity_amount) { investment.maturity_amount }

    context 'when amount is cumulative' do
      before do
        allow(investment).to receive(:cumulative).and_return(true)
        allow(investment).to receive(:interest_earned).and_return(9999.8)
      end

      it 'returns the rounded value of the cumulative amount' do
        expect(maturity_amount).to eq(10000)
      end
    end

    context 'when amount is not cumulative' do
      before do
        allow(investment).to receive(:cumulative).and_return(false)
        allow(investment).to receive(:initial_deposit).and_return(10000)
      end

      it 'returns the initial deposit' do
        expect(maturity_amount).to eq(10000)
      end
    end
  end

  describe '#interest_earned' do
    let(:interest_earned) { investment.interest_earned }
    # you may have various circumstances/edge cases where you would like to
    # test that the interest earned calculates what you would expect, and I
    # would put them in different `context` blocks, but for simplicity's sake
    # I'll just use one simple case here
    before do
      # using the Factory values from your question...
      allow(investment).to receive(:initial_deposit).and_return(250000)
      allow(investment).to receive(:rate_of_interest).and_return(9.5)
      # not sure of your default term value would be, so just use 1
      allow(investment).to receive(:term).and_return(1)
    end

    it 'calculates the interest earned' do
      # something seems a bit strange here given this passing test...
      # I assume there are other values that contribute to this calculation
      # that I'm missing
      expect(interest_earned).to eq(32436584.47265625)
    end
  end
end
```